# How can we count records from multiple joins when ID is used multiple times?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the record count from multiple tables, like this.

```
Select count(*)
From
(
Select  Hist.Common_Name,
        Veg.ID,
        EDSH.ID
From Hist_Event_View as Hist
Inner Join Vegtables as Veg
ON Hist.Common_Name = Veg.ID
INNER JOIN Final as Final
ON Hist.Common_Name = Final.ID) as Sub
```

The problem is that ID is being used multiple times, so SQL Server can't resolve which ID is coming from which table in the outer query, I think. How can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct, the duplicate ID's are the problem. You can handle this by giving the ID's an alias in the subquery:

```
Select count(*)
From
(
Select  Hist.Common_Name,
        Veg.ID as Veg_ID,
        EDSH.ID as EDSH_ID
From Hist_Event_View as Hist
Inner Join Vegtables as Veg
ON Hist.Common_Name = Veg.ID
INNER JOIN Final as Final
ON Hist.Common_Name = Final.ID) as Sub
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. I should have seen that before! Too early in the morning for this stuff! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: One more thing Vvdl...I'm getting this error message when I run your code...

Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

How do you deal with that?

Comment: I tried this in the outer query and it worked: Select COUNT_BIG(*) AS NumStreams

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be fixed by using an alias
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

But why do you need an outer select?
Why not just write:

```
Select  count(*)
From Hist_Event_View as Hist
Inner Join Vegtables as Veg
ON Hist.Common_Name = Veg.ID
INNER JOIN Final as Final
ON Hist.Common_Name = Final.ID
```

Comment: Yeha, you are right. I realized this just after I posted my question. VvdL solution is great, because I want to understand the logic with this kind of SubQuery. Thanks Roland and VvdL!!